# Filter all unique items like Google Docs

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Is there a quick/easy way to filter all unique items in an Excel 2013 column similar to the Google Docs "Unique" function?

Comment: When you say "filter" what exactly do you mean? You could create a pivot table - that will extract unique items.

Comment: There is still no built in worksheet function to do this. You need to write your own.

Comment: Do you want to filter the data while using Excel or do you want to do so programmatically?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1429899/2258  (Is it irony that the question asking to remove duplicates is a duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pretty answer, but it works.
Paste this as an array formula into cell **B2**:

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF(B$1:B1, A:A)=0)*(A:A<>"")), A:A)
```

With the column that needs to be filtered in **A:A**
Then drag / copy it down as far as is required.

[image]

[See it online in Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pUpiIWTdo_b96sAkomSFECU_BvRVh0EbQ_eR64NLvYs/edit?usp=sharing)

---

*Caveats*:

- Does not retain original order (resulting order is in fact the reverse)
- Does not automatically expand to cover all cells
- Not fast, not pretty, not transparent

---

*Footnotes*:

- It is trivial to use **IFERROR()** to filter out the **#N/A** errors, but I've not done this to keep the answer concise
- In the same vein the header of the column **A** is currently also returned. This can be fixed by changing **A:A** to **A$2:$25** in all 3 locations
- Original question was for Excel 2013, all of this *should* work there, but I wrote and tested it in Excel 2016
- I would love to hear suggestions on how to make the formula automatically expand down as far as required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Unique records only** feature in Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Under the DATA tab there is this: "Remove Duplicates". It'll do what you want.

[image: Remove Duplicates]

Comment: @pnuts Good point. NOTE TO ALL: Works in general. but see link for some interesting exceptions.

Comment: [A pivot table can overcome this challenge](http://superuser.com/a/644986/100579) related to cell content "types".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent to `=unique()` in Excel, and I hate having to work without it.

Without `=unique()` trying to find all of the unique values in a large array of data is impossible.  Take a dozen columns of a hundred+ entries and see what the unique values are across the whole mess and pop them nicely into a new columns.  I can't figure out how to do it in Excel, but in Gdocs it's simple:

```
=unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(A:M&",")),",")))
```

Using Filters, or PivotTables, or whatever, just doesn't cut it, and I haven't been able to find any hacked together ridiculous excel formula to do anything similar.

Answer (score -2):

[filter your data in spreadsheets](https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/03/filter-your-data-in-spreadsheets.html)

This might prove to be of some help to you.