# ways to eliminate the blank cell value in data validation list

Tags: excel-formula

How do I eliminate the blank cell value in data validation list without creating a new column to sort out the empty cell?

Formula for my define name

```
=MASTER!$C$2:INDEX(MASTER!$C$2:$C$100000,SUMPRODUCT(--(MASTER!$C$2:$C$100000<>"")))
```

Comment: What do you mean by eliminating the blank cell value ?

Comment: like do not show it. Currently for empty value, the drop down list will have a blank space which i do not want it to show

Comment: Are your Blanks in the middle of the list, or all at the end?

Comment: in the middle of the list

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets i would use `UNIQUE` which returns a list of unique values. This would remove empty values. To do it in excel is a little trickier but you can still do it:

[Filter all unique items like Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788711/filter-all-unique-items-like-google-docs)

Edit: As @m-douda mentioned this would also eliminate any duplicate records that are not empty.

Comment: That would erase duplicates as well, which might not be what OP wants

Comment: You are right. I will update the answer. However I assumed that this would actually be the expected behavior as when generating a drop down you definitely don't want duplicates as you don't have keys to link it to.