# Get rank of unique verion of an Excel range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the ranks from a list of values, but I want the ranks to be based on a unique version of the list. What I'd like to do is something like

=RANK.EQ(value, UNIQUE(list_of_values))

I can't find out how to get the unique values within the formula. I've seen answers on [how to output unique values to a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only), but my I don't require values to printed out, so I would hope there is an easier solution.

As an example, with a list like

`|Week Ending|

 |10/10/13|

|10/10/13|

|10/10/13|

|10/17/13|`

the closest I get is RANK.EQ(value, list_of_values, 1), which gives me

`|Week Ending|Week Number|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/17/13|     4|`

What I'm looking for is

`|Week Ending|Week Number|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/10/13|     1|

|10/17/13|     2|`

EDIT:

I didn't originally clarify this, but my values are not necessarily in sorted order.

Comment: Is the first column in sorted order? But your second column-name seems a little mis-leading..? I'm unsure how a 'Week Number' becomes a Rank? If they are, actually, week-numbers then the rank wouldn't be needed(?).

Comment: I didn't know about WeekNum when I asked the question, that is my solution here. My use case is assigning week numbers (as in Week 1 of campaign, week 2, etc) to events. But to answer your question, the first column would not necessarily be in sorted order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific example `WEEKNUM()` can be used to create an effective ranking of the dates:

```
=WEEKNUM(value, list_of_values, 1) + 1 - WEEKNUM(MIN(list_of_values))
```

This is because either all dates occur on the same day of the week, or dates occurring in the same week are considered to have the same rank.

"Week " can be concatenated to these values to create output of "Week 1", "Week 2" etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with fairly simple formulas, using two columns:

Assuming your dates are in `A1:A10`

`B1` contains this formula:  `=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$10)`

Copy that formula down to `B10`

`C1` contains this formula:  `=B1`

`C2` contains this formula:  `=IF(B2=B1,C1,C1+1)`

Copy that formula down to `C10`

You can also use the `RANK.EQ` function instead of `RANK`.

Comment: This is a nice solution if values are sorted, I should have specified, but my values are not necessarily in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Via Andy G, =WEEKNUM() solves my problem. More generally,

= WEEKNUM(value, list_of_values, 1) + 1 - WEEKNUM(MIN(list_of_values))

Gives numbers that can be used to make "Week 1, Week 2", etc labels.