# Excel 2010: VBA convert custom function code to a module with macro shortcut

Tags: function, vba, excel

**Info:**  Excel 2010
**Notes:** The code works exactly how I need, I am now wanting to automate it a little

I recently came across this code, it's for a custom function, however I can not create a button for it (like a macro), I would like to convert some of this code, however I don't know what to do or how to go about it.  I want to have a shortcut/button on my ribbon.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337453/2337102

```
Function listUnique(rng As Range) As Variant
Dim row As Range
Dim elements() As String
Dim elementSize As Integer
Dim newElement As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim distance As Integer
Dim result As String

elementSize = 0
newElement = True

For Each row In rng.Rows
    If row.Value <> "" Then
        newElement = True
        For i = 1 To elementSize Step 1
            If elements(i - 1) = row.Value Then
                newElement = False
            End If
        Next i
        If newElement Then
            elementSize = elementSize + 1
            ReDim Preserve elements(elementSize - 1)
            elements(elementSize - 1) = row.Value
        End If
    End If
Next

distance = Range(Application.Caller.Address).row - rng.row

If distance < elementSize Then
    result = elements(distance)
    listUnique = result
Else
    listUnique = ""
End If
End Function
```

Results with the ability to:

> Just enter =listUnique(range) to a cell. The only parameter is range
>   that is an ordinary Excel range. For example: A$1:A$28 or H$8:H$30.

**I would like the following:**
Create a macro button with an a popup `Inputbox` to ask for a range.

**Usage:**

1)  I am in the cell where I require the list to begin (BA9)
2)  I click the custom module/macro button & popup box asks me the range (G$8:G$10000)
3)  The result then autofills in column (BA)

Lastly, can the code be amended so that the restriction of "The first cell where you call the function must be in the same row where the range starts." be removed so that I can use a reference from another sheet within the same workbook.

I apologise if I should have gone direct to the coder, the thread that it was in is old & I thought given the amount of change I'm asking for it may be better suited in its own question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach:** (you can use `RemoveDuplicates` method instead function `listUnique`)

Just assign this `Sub` to your custom button:

```
Sub testRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim actCell As Range
    Dim res As Variant

    Set actCell = ActiveCell

    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetRange Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "User has pressed cancel"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    targetRange.Copy
    actCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    actCell.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

---

**Second approach:** (if you'd like to use function `listUnique`)

Here is another `listUnique` function. You can get list of unique elements usign **[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)** object (it is better suited for your purposes):

```
Function listUnique(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim row As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        If row.Value <> "" Then
            dict.Add row.Value, row.Value
        End If
    Next

    Dim res As Variant
    ReDim res(1 To dict.Count)

    res = dict.Items

    Set dict = Nothing
    listUnique = Application.Transpose(res)
End Function
```

then you can call it using following `Sub` (you can assign it to custom button):

```
Sub test()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim actCell As Range
    Dim res As Variant

    Set actCell = ActiveCell

    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetRange = Application.InputBox("Please highlight the cell for TARGET", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetRange Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "User has pressed cancel"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    res = listUnique(targetRange)

    actCell.Resize(UBound(res)) = res
End Sub
```

**Note:** if you're going to call this `listUnique` function direct from worksheet (as UDF function), you should select destination range (in example `D10:D20`), *with selected range* enter formula `=listUnique(A1:A10)` in formula bar, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I'll run them and post back, it's 3am here :)  So far looks good, thank you.

Comment: just ran both, I can get option 1 to work, but not option 2. Option 2 gives me a column of either blank or 0.  But Option 1 is perfect!  Thank you :D

Comment: Sorry, my fault..I've updated my asnwer with new `listUnique` function:)

Comment: Do I need to activate the dictionary? I can get it to where it asks for the cells, I have used both numeric (date) and alpa cells, and then nothing happens after that.

Comment: Update - I can get it to work now, the only issue is for dates with yyyy-mmm-dd some result in dd-mm-yyyy (correct: 2014-Jan-04, error: (4/01/2014) April 1st 2014).  I have tried to override the format but it worsens.  But on text only this is great :D

Comment: Text to columns fixed that glitch