# How to grab the value of an excel column based on a unique value in another column

Tags: excel

I have the following excel sheet and I'm trying to make a calculation that says how many of the courses are Live. I have duplicate course values in rows so I need a way to say distinct courses and grab the delivery method tied to it.

```
Course   Delivery_Method
16679    Live
16679    Live
16743    Live
16861    In-House
```

I'd like the output of the calculation to be:

```
Live Courses: 2
```

It may be important to note that 1 course will never have a live row and an in-house row. They will always be the same.

Comment: These links may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only and http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/#uniquedistinct

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much better way to do it, but this is a roundabout method I have used before.

It requires a second worksheet that does the calculations. We will call your current sheet 'Sheet 1' and the Calculating sheet 'Sheet 2'.  I am also calling [Course] 'Col A' and [Delivery_Method] 'Col B'.

**On Sheet 2, create these Columns:**

**A. [Course]**
Copy from 'Sheet 1' and paste to 'Sheet 2'

**B. [Leave Blank]**
You will be creating a list in Column B that shows all items in Column A, but with no duplicates. *If there is anything in Column B, Clear Contents (see why below).*  Select Col A. On the Data tab, select Advanced.  Click 'Copy to another location', at 'Copy to:' enter '$B:$B' Click 'Unique records only'.  Click 'OK'.  Col B should now be populated.

Why you need to clear Col B: 1) The filter likes to drop the existing header in, so if that space is occupied, you'll get an error message; 2) if your new sorted list is shorter than your old sorted list, then you'll end up with extra fields at the bottom that are from your old list.

*One more thing - If you ever use this feature again, you need to know that it can only be done within the same sheet.  You can't use a 'Copy To' location that's on another sheet or document.*

**C. [Live]**
Enter this formula in all cells: =CountIfs([Sheet1!A:A,Bb2,'Sheet 1'!B:B,"Live")

**D. [In-House]**
Enter this formula in all cells: =CountIfs([Sheet1!A:A,B2,'Sheet 1'!B:B,"In-House")

**E. [Total Live]**
In row 2, enter: =Sum[$C:$C]

**F. [Total In-House]**
In row 2, enter: =Sum[$D:$D]

You can also just do an auto-sum at the bottom of your [Live] and [In-House] Columns instead of using columns E and F.

Each time you do this, you should double-check the bottom of the list to be sure you have formulas to match all of the lines populated in Col B.