# Excel - get smaller table of unique preserving properties of original table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that's similar to the following (input):

```
_element___|_color__
 494       | red
 592       | blue
 493       | red
 139       | green
 393       | blue
 496       | black
```

And I want to get a table that looks like this (output):

```
_color_____|_elements__
 red       | 493, 494
 blue      | 393, 592
 green     | 139
 black     | 496
```

I would also accept an answer that gets the following output:

```
_color_____|_element__|_element__|_element__|
 red       | 493      | 494      |          |
 blue      | 393      | 592      |          |
 green     | 139      |          |          |
 black     | 496      |          |          |
```

I know from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only) how to get the column "color" on the left done. I don't know how to make the column "elements" on the right done - order doesn't matter.

I *prefer* without macros, but with macros is fine too! - I don't know enough Excel to judge which is best. I also need a better title for this question.

```
___EDIT____
```

Looking through the code of the answer by @Gary's Student, I made this function below:

```
Function GetElement(elements As Range, colors As Range, color As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Nels As Long: Nels = elements.Count + 1
    Dim str As String: str = ""

    If IsError(Cells(color.Row, color.Column).Value) Then
        GetElement = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 2 To Nels
            If Cells(color.Row, color.Column).Value = Cells(i, colors.Column).Value Then
                If str = "" Then
                    str = Cells(i, elements.Column).Value
                Else
                    str = str & ", " & Cells(i, elements.Column).Value
                End If
            End If
    Next i

    GetElement = str
End Function
```

Using this function on the cells of the column at the right of "**Color**", using `f4` to lock both first and second argument to the range of the columns "**Element**" and the right "**Color**" got the correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we start with:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub TableOrganizer()
  Dim st As String, i As Long, N As Long
  Dim M As Long, j As Long
  Range("B:B").Copy Range("C1")
  Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
  N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  M = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To N
    st = Cells(i, "C").Value
    t = ""
    For j = 2 To M
      If st = Cells(j, "B").Value Then
        t = t & "," & Cells(j, "A").Value
      End If
    Next j
    Cells(i, "D").Value = "'" & Mid(t, 2)
  Next i
End Sub
```

We will end up with:

[image]