# Find duplicates in two sheets and show unique values

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I would like to know how to compare two columns in two different sheets, and only show the unique values.

I have two lists of email addresses, yet there are some duplicates in them. Would like to know how to get only the unique values of these sheets.

I have already tried the count() function/formula, yet it only counts and displays a number.

Example:

List 1:

```
- email@address.com
- otheremail@address.com
- someemail@address.com
```

List 2:

```
- email@address.com
- someonesemail@address.com
- someemail@address.com
```

In this example `otheremail@address.com` and `someonesemail@address.com` would be the unique values. I would like these to be displayed after the function being executed.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only

Comment: Thansk Ian, but it seems it still only removes duplicates and doesnt show only the unique values. Or i am doing something wrong..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vlookup is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Could be yes, but how? :P

Comment: You insert a Vlookup function.. By clicking Formulas - insert function - Vlookup.

You can find a full explanation of using the Vlookup function here:
[link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the lists by copying and pasting them into one column, then insert a pivot table with the stacked list as the data source. Pull in email address and it will have 1 row per email.

Or, one you have a stacked list, on the data tab, you can use the remove duplicate function to return a distinct list of values.