# How to show only unique values in a list?

Tags: excel, notepad++

If I have a list like the following: `1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6`.

I would like to somehow obtain the result of `2, 3, 6`. So that is, find the duplicate values, and not just remove the duplicates, but actually delete the values which were duplicate entirely (or rather, only return the values which weren't found to be duplicate).

Is there a way to do this in Notepad++/Excel or something else?

Comment: Maybe this would help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only

Answer (score 0):

Well of course I figure it out 5 minutes after I ask...

I can just put the list into excel, highlight the duplicates, sort them by cell color and then delete the duplicates (or save the non-duplicates).

Comment: You could also copy the list, then go to Data-> Remove Duplicates on your new list. This will leave you with unique numbers. Then just put a `Countif()` next to that to see how many times a number appears. If it's `1`, then that's a result to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to use a Pivot table and then Count the occurrences, sort on the count and then copy your remaining.

So (assuming Excel 2013 or higher):
1. Given a list of numbers (or anything) in a column, name your column in the cell above the first row.
2. Click in your list
3. Select the "Insert" menu tab and click "PivotTable" (far left)
4. Click "Ok" in the pop up
5. In the PivotTable Fields section on the right side of screen, drag your column down to the Rows quadrant
6. Drag your Column down to the Values column also
7. If the Values box shows "Sum of ", click the drop down next to that
8. Select "Value Field Settings"
9. Select "Count" and click ok
10. In the Pivot table, right click on one of the count values and select Sort/Sort Smallest to Largest

Now you should have all the single instances at the top. Simply copy and paste where you want it.