# Assign a contract to a owner

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new on VBA, pls be patient. I have a list of contracts and need to assign each unique contract to someone and in case the contract repeat in another cell it should be assigned to the same person. I have no idea how to do it. So basically, it's just for each unique value in column A insert a value in a column C from a list in the column B

```
Column A            Column B            Column C
MXAACIX             Alice
MXAAFO5             Carolina
MXAAFO5             Jefferson
MXAAFO5             Erik
MXAAFO5
MXAAB3T
MXAAB96
MXAAFDE
MXAAFDE
MXAAFDE
MXAAEK7
MXAAEK7
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written thus far and explain the errors / bugs you are running into. Also, you need to elaborate upon the logic you would like to use in distributing the contracts: what happens if there are less unique contracts than there are names? what happens if there are (for example) 10 unique contracts? Who gets more contracts than others?

Comment: If you make the assignments on one "master" sheet then you can use `VLOOKUP()` on all the other sheets to pull the assignees.

Comment: You can get the unique contracts by implementing this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only But afterwards the question still remains: how do you want to split the (in this case) 6 contracts among 4 people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard worksheet formula that can accomplish this. In C2 as,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C1, MATCH(A2, A$1:A1, 0)),
         INDEX(B$2:B$5, MOD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A$2:A2))-1, 4)+1))
```

To make that truly dynamic according to the number and variety of contracts and the number of owners, the formula becomes a little more complicated.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C1, MATCH(A2, A$1:A1, 0)),
         INDEX(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )),
                  MOD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A$2:A2&""))-1, 
                      COUNTA(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))))+1))
```

[image: contract_to_owner]

---

<sup>Good documentation on individual worksheet functions can be found at [Excel function (by category)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb).</sup>