# Formula for unmatched row cell and display value in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, formulas, vba

What is the formula for unmatched row cell and display in one column as
mentioned in the attached work sheet

Worksheet to get Result and Header column values

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A8dh.png]

I am using this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A2:M2,1,FALSE),"")
```

But it displays only one values in Result column.

Comment: Question is unclear to me.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only). you'll need to make adjustments for your data, but you can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native worksheet formulas simply do not handle string concatenation well. Even the new string functions that are being introduced such as [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)¹ and the updated [CONCAT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2)² have difficulty with conditional concatenation beyond TEXTJOIN's blank/no-blank parameter.

Here are a pair of User Defined Functions (aka **UDF**) that will perform the tasks.

```
Function udfUniqueList(rng As Range, _
        Optional delim As String = ",")
    Dim str As String, r As Range

    'always truncate ranges as parameters to the usedrange
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    str = rng(1).Value2
    For Each r In rng
        If Not CBool(InStr(1, delim & str & delim, delim & r.Value2 & delim, vbTextCompare)) Then
            str = str & delim & r.Value2
        End If
    Next r

    udfUniqueList = str

End Function

Function udfRogueHeaders(rng As Range, hdr As Range, _
        Optional delim As String = ",", _
        Optional bBlnks As Boolean = False)
    Dim i As Long, bas As String, str As String

    'always truncate ranges as parameters to the usedrange
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    'reshape hdr to be identical to rng
    Set hdr = hdr.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

    bas = rng(1).Value2
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        If (CBool(Len(UCase(rng.Cells(i).Value2))) And Not bBlnks) Or _
          bBlnks Then
            If UCase(bas) <> UCase(rng.Cells(i).Value2) Then
                str = str & IIf(CBool(Len(str)), delim, vbNullString) & _
                        hdr.Cells(i).Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    udfRogueHeaders = str

End Function
```

In P2:Q2 as,

```
=udfUniqueList(A2:L2)
=udfRogueHeaders(A2:L2, A$1:L$1)
```

**[Results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Formula%20for%20matching%20multiple%20row%20cell%20including%20blank%20cell.xlsb):**

[image: udfRogueHeaders]

---

¹ <sub>The [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) is being introduced with Excel 2016 ⁄ Office 365 ⁄ Excel Online. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>The new [CONCAT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) for Excel 2016 ⁄ Office 365 ⁄ Excel Online is intended to replace the older [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-5B0392B2-94EF-49EA-8532-4FDD3A69D362) with improved functionality.</sub>