# Match partial string with another list of strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a few columns in an excel spreadsheet. Basically, I am trying to match partial string from one cell to another. I need help creating the results in column B and column C below in excel. Preferably formula. If not, vba is fine as well. The goal is to compare List_A to column D, E, F. Thanks!

[image]

I tried the following:
1. Split out List_A into different columns by using comma delimited. But did not know how to go forward because values in Column D,E,F might not always in order. So I can't compare cell to cell.

Comment: Any thoughts on your end yet or are you just waiting for us to write the solution for you?

Comment: What have you even tried?, this is not a place for asking begging of code.

Comment: I split out List_A by the comma into different columns and then didn't know how to go forward...

Answer (score 2):

You are just in time to use the new [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) available in [excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016) / [[image]office365](/questions/tagged/office365) and [excel-online](/questions/tagged/excel-online).

[image: textjoin_xlol]

The formula for column C is based on the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671).

Comment: I do not have excel 2016. I am using 2010.

Comment: Well, there are many examples of VBA UDF string concatenation functions on this site. I know because I've written at least a dozen myself. See [udfUniqueList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092790/formula-for-unmatched-row-cell-and-display-value-in-one-column/36094199#36094199).

Comment: I have Excel 2016 locally installed but I do not have a subscription. So, I cannot use it either. Having Office 2016 does not suffice (unfortunately).

Comment: Yes, with xl2016 desktop you need an Office 365 subscription but you can still use it online.

Comment: I didn't know that and just wanted to try it now. Unfortunately, Excel Online is too smart for me. It seems to change the language automatically to where I am currently connecting from. My browser is English, my system is English, and my OneDrive account is English. Still, Excel online knows better and changes to the local language (menu bar & formulas) and I am lost. Tried to fix it but couldn't find a solution. So, I am giving up for now.

Comment: @ralph - Change the URL to force the 'market' or regional area. e.g. `https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx?omkt=en-US`

Comment: @Jeeped: Thank you. I clicked / opened your link. Still, all is opened with local language (which they can only get from my IP as everything else is English). I also looked for the option to change languages as mentioned here: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-language-used-outlookcom-office-online-more Still, OneDrive knows better.