# VBA: Count unique values that meet two criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have three columns: ID, events, and month. I need to get the count of events by month unique by ID.

So far I have the count of events by month (e.g. 1806 unique logins in May) using CountIfs(Range("B2:B276609"), EventName, Range(C2:C76602"), m)).

How do I filter this above count so only the unique IDs within that count is being used? Note that I have to loop this through a bunch of event types and months.

To make this clearer, let me provide some sample data:

```
ID  Event  Month
1   Login  May 16
2   click  July 16
1   Save   June 16
1   Login  May 16
3   Save   June 16
```

From this I need to get the following info:

```
1 unique login in May 16
2 unique saves in June 16
1 unique click in July 16
```

Comment: This solution allows you to get all unique values from a table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only If you require *unique* values based on two columns then you can (1) create a helper column which combines the two columns or (2) combine the columns in the formula with an array formula before comparing the values for their uniqueness.

Comment: r u interested in a way to do it without vba? if so what version of excel do you have?

Comment: This is a simple aggregate SQL query which **can** be run with Excel VBA, calling ADO on the current workbook. No nested loops or if/then conditionals needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel's inbuilt [remove duplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) function.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C76602").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Yes! Can't believe I didn't think of doing this simple pre-step.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link in Ralph's comments which can be found here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only) you get:

**To know how many unique items you have you can use this regular formula:**

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(COUNTIF(Colors,"<"&Colors),COUNTIF(Colors,"<"&Colors)),1))
```

I then extended this to multiple columns just change the countif formulas to countifs.  (different ranges used obviously).

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,"<"&$A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,"<"&$B$1:$B$10),COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,"<"&$A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,"<"&$B$1:$B$10)),1))
```