# Getting unique values from excel table

Tags: excel

I'm trying to apply these
[Getting unique values in Excel by using formulas only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only)

to my table, but as a result i get only 0's

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. Place `=G1` in `L1`
2. Place `{=INDEX($G$1:$G$999,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$G$1:$G$999),0,0),0))}` in `L2` and copy it down.