# Array formula to return an ARRAY without duplicates, without VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I would like to know whether it's possible to return an array from a single cell formula, which is filtered to remove duplicates, and which is built purely on Excel formulas.

I'm aware of approaches to return a *list* of values where the duplicates are removed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429899/6609896)), where the list is spread over multiple cells. However I specifically want to return an array intermediate.

E.g. For the list in `A1:A5`, I can get an array of values `{0.1,0.2,0.2,0.7,0.3}`, from which I want a second array `{0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3}`, as an intermediate in an array formula. [Current approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159534/6609896) use single-end anchored ranges (like `C$1:C1`) to iterate through the items in the array geometrically (by dragging down column C). I would like to leave the array un-iterated, within the formula. I can then manipulate this as I would any other array.

All this should take place in a single cell if possible.

#### NB

Both [MacroMarc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295491/6609896) and [Barry Houdini's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295147/6609896) answers are perfectly valid, and I ran a speed check on each - there was negligible difference (any difference was smaller than the variation between test runs). Both scored ~ 1.0±0.2 ms

Comment: so you want `0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3` as your output in one cell?

Comment: write a udf with a static dictionary object.

Comment: @ScottCraner the array `{0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3}`, yes. But only as an intermediate step (how could a single cell display an array!), I can then manipulate the array with other formulae in the same cell. `SUM()` for example, or `MATCH()`

Comment: @Jeeped For this particular use (with portability/accessibility in mind) I don't want to use VBA. I was also not aware that UDFs can return an entire array that Excel recognises (like with `=SUM({myUDF()})`) but that's another question altogether

Comment: That is a big formula, vba is better.

Comment: And a UDF can return an array to a formula.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me.

Comment: I know the question is for an array formula, but a PivotTable is portable, and will return a unique list.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Yeah, there's a few ways of filtering with lists and tables and things. But the advantage I see in array formulae is the live updating, in fact it's really the only reason I use them at all. And I don't *believe* you can re-filter when data changes without breaking into a `Worksheet_Change` event (or otherwise using VBA)

Comment: Ah. Yeah I use VBA and a Worksheet_Change event to trap any updates to the source data and then refresh the PivotTable. Or I put a big callout saying "Please right click on this thing and choose refresh".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used a defined name for the Range (A1:A5) and called it myList. You can do the same, or substitute in the Address $A$1:$A$5 if you wish:

`{=INDEX(myList, N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH(myList, myList, 0) = ROW(myList), ROW(myList)*{1,1})))), 1)}`

**EDIT:** Above wasn't robust to handle if the column list is further down the sheet, and a shorter minrow routine courtesy of OP:

`{=INDEX(myList, N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH(myList, myList, 0)=ROW(myList)-MIN(ROW(myList))+1, (ROW(myList)-MIN(ROW(myList))+1)*{1,1})))), 1)}`

This should be ok for you. Needless to say, these are array formulas..

Comment: Nice one! - shorter than mine but a little less robust - as it stands mylist must start at row 1 whereas mine will accommodate any vertical range

Comment: true will edit - sloppy - it should check the first row. Done!

Comment: Excellent! I like the use of `MODE.MULT` - I've never used that function in this context

Comment: Thanks. I quite like it as a quick way of reducing/filtering an array in Excel formulas in conjunction with the IF formula...

Comment: Maybe `ROW(INDEX(myList, 1, 1))` could become `MIN(ROW(myList))` for simplicity?

Answer (score 3):

This formula will return a sorted array without duplicates, e.g. for your example

`{0.1;0.2;0.3;0.7}`

`=SMALL(IF(MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5,0)=ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1)+1,A1:A5),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(0+(0<(FREQUENCY(A1:A5,A1:A5)))))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

......or this version will keep the order

`=INDEX(A1:A5,N(IF({1},SMALL(IF(MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5,0)=ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1)+1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1)+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(0+(0<(FREQUENCY(A1:A5,A1:A5))))))))))`

Comment: Can this code be modified to preserve the original sorting? Such as `{0.1,0.2,0.2,0.7,0.3}` ->`{0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3}`

Comment: I added another version that will keep the order based on the first instance of any duplicates

Comment: Nice one Barry, I use a similar technique to your edited unsorted version :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula to sum the unique, it requires the use of TEXTJOIN() which is only available with Office 365 Excel:

```
=SUM( IF(ISERROR(FIND(TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999)),MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999))),--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

You can replace SUM with many different formula.

[image]

If one does not have Office 365 Excel then vba and or helper columns are the only method available.

---

Edit:

To remove the False from the array and return the 3rd non duplicate in the array we can wrap it in another TEXTJOIN:

```
=--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,IF(ISERROR(FIND(TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999)),MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999))),--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999)),"")),(3-1)*999,999))
```

The `3` in the `(3-1)*999` can be replaced by anything that returns the Index number desired.

Still an array formula that needs Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you want to return the relative position in then use this array:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))/(--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,IF(ISERROR(FIND(TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999)),MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999))),--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,A:A),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999+1,999)),"")),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(A:A)))-1)*999,999))=B1),1)
```

[image]

---

I gave you the long formula for creating the array but for the sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5))
```

would be sufficient.

And for the Average:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5))
```

There are many work arounds that are shorter and better if you know what you want.

Comment: So close, but the internal array contains `False` for duplicates: i.e. returns `{0.1,0.2,False,0.7,0.3}` and not simply `{0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3}`. That's fine for `SUM()`, but something like `MATCH()`, the additional element bumps everything along the queue. I agree there's certainly a case by case shorter version, but it's a problem I've come across before so I wanted a complete general case. Probably not do-able, as I've never seen Excel shrink an array (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: This is great, the last one you added was what I was *secretly* after, and I'm definitely bookmarking these functions 'cos you have most covered. But we still don't really have the general case, the plain, filtered array. *I'm fascinated by all the little tricks here by the way - `--` for text (I only knew that for boolean conversions)* `TEXTJOIN`, `AGGREGATE`

Comment: Or so it seemed... (just flagging you in case you didn't see the new solns.)