# Combine 2 or more columns into 1 column in excel

Tags: excel, array-formulas

i need to refrence A1:A5 (which will return {1;2;3;4;5}) and then add B2:B5 to the end of that (which will return {6;7;8;9;10}), so the finished product will look like this {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}.

does anyone have any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the array desired:

```
INDEX(A1:B5,N(IF(1,MOD(ROW(1:10)-1,5)+1)),N(IF(1,INT((ROW(1:10)-1)/5)+1)))
```

You can test it by doing:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A1:B5,N(IF(1,MOD(ROW(1:10)-1,5)+1)),N(IF(1,INT((ROW(1:10)-1)/5)+1))),7)
```

Which, when confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode, will return the value in B2.

[image]

Comment: THAT IS AMAZING!! i will display what i did with that soon, but can you please explain:

1) why you use the (seemingly superfluous) N function?
2) why you use the (seemingly superfluous) If function, as you just typed TRUE in the logical statemnt...??
3) i always thought that index cant take array formulas/constants in the row/column index argument. can you explain how yours worked?
[ 4) why doesn't microsoft make a larger evaluate formula window :)???]

Thanks so much!! you are amazing!

Comment: The `N` and `IF` combination return arrays to the INDEX which it will accept.  It is a loop hole that works. Not sure why that magical combination works but it does.

Comment: I am absolutely blown away by this (and the one who figured that out..)! Had i known this earlier i would have saved tons of time!!!. i recently did this formula to add the second and fourth column of an index array:  =sum(sumproduct(index(A1:A5,)*{0,1,0,1,0})....   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now, to take it a step further, can we delete the duplicates in the same formula?? i tried playing around with it for a while with no success (yet). (to make it even crazier, how about deleting duplicates and sorting..... but at least deleting duplicates..)

Comment: @Dave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294089/array-formula-to-return-an-array-without-duplicates-without-vba