# Create a unique list even if original list contains cells with =""

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A                    B 
1   Original List          Unique List
2   Product A               Product A
3   Product A               Product B
4   Product B               Product C
5   =""
6   Product A
7   Product C
8   Product B
9   =""
10  Product C
```

In **Column A** I have list which contains several products multiple times. My goal is now to create a list of all unique items in **Column B**.

To achive this I used the formula from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only) post in **Cells B2:B10**:

```
B2:B10 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(SUM(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$10)),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,"<"&$A$2:$A$10),0)),"")
```

and I get the following result:

```
         A                    B 
1   Original List        Unique List
2   Product A            
3   Product A            Product A
4   Product B            Product B
5   =""                  Product C
6   Product A
7   Product C
8   Product B
9   =""
10  Product C
```

This result comes pretty close to the list I want. The only issue is that the formula cannot handle the formula `=""` which is in some cells in **Column A**. Instead of starting the list in **Cell B2** it starts the list in **Cell B3**.

How do I have to mody the formula so it also works in case there are cells with `=""` in the original list?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use excel's built in 'Remove Duplicates' function?:

```
Range("$A$2:$A$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a "helper" column.  In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",1+MAX($C$1:C1)))
```

and copy down.  Column **C** assigns a simple sequential value to each item in column **A** from which data will be extracted.  Then in **B2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$C$2:$C$10,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Note:**

This method uses normal formulas rather than array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Advanced Filter`.

Use a Formula criteria such as `=LEN(A5)>0`  where `A5` is the first cell with data.  And then check the `Unique Records Only` in the Advanced Filter dialog.  You can either filter in place, or to a new location