# How to understand the code in post on "Getting unique values in Excel ..."?

Tags: excel, vba, unique-values

Referring to [answered Jun 27 '13 at 7:43 by totymedli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337453/4300579)
and [answered Apr 13 '16 at 0:53 by Meir Shachar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36586664/4300579)

I do prefer the VBA solution although the OP did not ask for one. However, I am able to parse and understand most of the linked responses above, other than the line:

`distance = Range(Application.Caller.Address).row - rng.row`

It appears that the posters are using this construct to determine if the resultant range (or array?) is greater than zero length to avoid creation of an empty Variant return value. If so, I fail to see the need for this and am able to create useful output without references to the integer `distance`.

I *have* attempted my due diligence, however, the usually cryptic [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller) was less than useful for me. If someone could please explain the use/nature of the `Application.Caller.Address` construct (even better - in this particular instance) I could better judge if I actually need to use it.

Comment: `distance = Application.Caller.Row - rng.row` is more concise - there's no need to extract the Address and then turn it back into a Range...   Note also you can use `Application.ThisCell` in place of `Application.Caller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Application.Caller.Address` in a UDF (User Defined Function), it returns the address of the cell that contains the formula that is calling the UDF.

For example if cell `B2` contains formula `=listUnique(A1:A10)` then `Application.Caller.Address` would return the address `B$2$`.

Comment: Thank you. Confirms that for my intent of using within a UserForm code module I can safely ignore/work-around the references to `distance`. Many thanx.