# Adding B where A is same [in excel]

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I want to add two rows where a variable is same.

***sample.csv:***

```
A        B
corn     56
apple    43   
banana   54
corn     87
mango    63
apple    67
corn     30
```

I want to add values of B where A is same and want to store answer in another column as follows:

```
corn    162
apple   110
banana   54
mango    63
```

Can I do  this in `excel`? If yes, then what is the formula for that? I searched a-lot but unable to reach solution.

Comment: Traditionally you do this with a pivot table. Otherwise you can do it with [`sumif`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), provided you first create a list of unique items [in one way or another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429899/11683).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

1. Select an empty cell.
2. Go to Data - Data Tools - Consolidate
3. Select the range (both columns)
4. Press add
5. Tick Left column
6. Press ok