# Ignore Duplicates and Create list of Unique Values separated with commas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A   Column B  Column C         Column D
a          a         a, a, b, c, c    a, b, c
a          b
b          c
c
c
```

Can anybody please help me with my problem? I need unique values in one cell.

```
B2=INDEX($A$2:$A$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$6), 0))
```

So far I've found how to make list separated with commas.

```
C2 = {=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:A6)}
```

How to apply Index or other function to  get unique values in D2 ?

Comment: Copy the source and paste in another set of cells, then use the "remove duplicates" button... Or if it has to be a function, check on here - several questions around this. See this for one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429899/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work in `D2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0)=MATCH(ROW(A2:A6),ROW(A2:A6)),A2:A6,""))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Unable to test this myself, no `TEXTJOIN()` on my Excel 2016 :(

Answer (score 0):

there is problem to use function "textjoin" in Excel 2010 ... hmmm some of my school computers runs only 2010 version.
So, I've found this VBA:
[string concatenation](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/stringconcatenation.aspx)